# How to access variable in Rust after it has been moved in a closure with "move" keyword?

Tags: rust, closures, ownership

```
    let stream = device.build_input_stream(
        &config.into(),
        move |data, _: &_| {
            let b = write_input_data::<f32, f32>(data);
            println!("b: {}", b.len());
        },
        |err| {
            eprintln!("an error occurred on stream: {}", err);
        },
        None
    ).unwrap();

fn write_input_data<T, U>(input: &[T]) -> Vec<U>
where
    T: Sample,
    U: Sample + From<T> + hound::Sample + std::fmt::Debug,
{
    let mut buffer = Vec::new();
    for sample in input.iter() {
        buffer.push(U::from(*sample));
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Problem:

I want to access all the data that write_input_data creates. As the closure has a "move" keyword, I'm not able to create any vector in main function and access the data later.

Things I tried:

1. Removing "move" keyword
2. Creating a vector in the main function to which I would later push the data(variable called b)
3. Pass a reference to the write_input_data (useless, move keyword also moves the ownership)

Is this even possible?

Comment: What is the implementation of `build_input_stream`?

Comment: [It's certainly possible to exfiltrate the information without `move` keyword](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=169cb2f913437c235e52fdc2b7b9d3e7) but that depends on the types on the various functions, and on their behaviour. Given you've provided almost nothing usable, it's hard to say for sure. But worst case scenario [you can always use refcounting and inner mutability](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2ed2a1c7a560f43dc7b08078a6719860).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://docs.rs/cpal/latest/cpal/traits/trait.DeviceTrait.html#method.build_input_stream

The code is based on a cpal library, didn't want to use another function to create a MRE because I am not sure of the implementation - I could've given a bad example.

Comment: @Masklinn thanks btw, I think this may work, I'll check on it and edit the question with mocked functions if it turns out to solve the problem

Comment: Unless you can `move` it back as in package it up as a return value somewhere, you're stuck with shared access, as in via a tool like `Arc`. A `move` surrenders the value to that closure, you can't keep using it after.

Comment: I managed to do it with

Arc & Mutex :) Thanks! I'll post a solution for other people after I understand why exactly it's workin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let v = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));
    let v2 = v.clone();

    let stream = device.build_input_stream(
        &config.into(),
        move |data, _: &_| {
            let b = write_input_data::<f32, f32>(data);
            println!("b len: {}", b.len());
            let mut vec = v2.lock().unwrap();
            vec.extend(b);
        },
        |err| {
            eprintln!("an error occurred on stream: {}", err);
        },
        None
    ).unwrap();
    
    stream.play(); 
    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));

    let mut vec = v.lock().unwrap();
    println!("vec len: {}", vec.len());
    drop(stream);
}

fn write_input_data<T, U>(input: &[T]) -> Vec<U>
where
    T: Sample,
    U: Sample + From<T> + hound::Sample,
{
    let mut buffer = Vec::new();
    for sample in input.iter() {
        buffer.push(U::from(*sample));
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

To everyone having the same issue in the future, this was the answer. It's important to have two instances of a vector ( v.clone() ) as the variable ownership is moved in the |move| function, but both v and v2 point to the same inner value. Arc and Mutex, although I don't have a perfect understanding of, allow for the variable to be written by both main function & write_input_data.